# How many energy tanks are there in Metroid Prime 3?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

I am at the point of no return in *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption* for the Nintendo Wii, and before I continue and can't get back, I want to make sure I have all the suit upgrades possible before I continue on.

What is the maximum number of energy tanks I can collect? Please **do not** tell me *where* they are. I want to find them myself. I just want to know if I have them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://metroid.retropixel.net/mprime3/items4.php) lists all the locations but does say at the top that there are 14 energy tanks to find.

[This page](http://uk.gamespot.com/features/6177947/p-31.html) also lists 14 tanks.

Comment: @Josh - no problem, at least you'll have a quick reference if you're stuck on the last two or three ;)

Comment: Thanks again Chris! I just found the 14th one and didn't have to look at the lists :-)